# Plesk scheduled tasks doesn't work

Tags: cron, plesk

I rented a dedicated server with Plesk 11, I scheduled a database backup cron-job to performs daily backup, below is the commands:

```
mysqldump -u admin -p`cat /etc/psa/.psa.shadow` database1 > /var/backups/db_backup_`date +\%Y\%m\%d\%H\%M\%S`.sql
```

when the command is executed, I received a notification with errors:

```
cat: /etc/psa/.psa.shadow: No such file or directory
-: date: command not found
-: date: command not found
-: /var/backups/db_backup_.sql: No such file or directory
```

I tried logon as root user in SSH console to run the same command, the backup file was created successfully.

I cannot figured out why Plesk does not do the same? please help.

Answer (score 0):

Create shell script with this command, add execution bit and run this script from Plesk scheduled task.